# Limiting maximum number of rows in Oracle Database and delete old rows as new ones are inserted

Tags: database, oracle

Essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201185/automatically-enforcing-a-max-database-table-size-by-dropping-old-rows), but since it's 6 years old I figured it might be worth checking if there has been any added feature to Oracle DB.

Basically, what we want to do is ensure that our archive table in Oracle DB doesn't grow too large, and would therefore like to set a maximum amount of rows to keep, and to delete the oldest row as a new row is inserted.

I haven't been able to find any simpler way of doing it than a cron job cleaning up at regular intervals, but I thought it could be worth asking if anyone else knows of a way nice of doing it within the database itself.

*Edit in reply to Florin Ghita's comment*: Rows are inserted one per transaction. We're thinking of limiting the database to around 5 or 10 million rows, with approximately 700 000 rows inserted per day (so in total keeping about a week worth of data), which gives a mean number of 8 rows per second (though peak times will certainly see this number spiking to at least double).

Comment: in what manner are the rows inserted? one per transaction, one per statement, many on statement, etc? How many rows in the table and how many rows inserted per second? (FYI, Oracle does't changed in its core too much in the last 6 years, so the problem is the same. The concurency forces you to maintain an _aproximate_ number of rows)

Comment: Rather than a cron job, I'd look at DBMS_Scheduler -- keep your database maintenance code in your database.

Comment: @David Aldridge: Thanks, I'll have a look at that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the old records to magically disappear on new inserts, I think this is not really feasible. You *could* write a trigger to delete records when inserting a new one, but you would get error ORA-04091, when using a query on the same table for the insert (e.g. `insert into mytable (a,b) select 123, max(b)+1 from mytable;`.

If you know for certain such conflict will never happen, then go ahead:

```
create or replace trigger trg_crop_mytable
before insert on mytable for each row
begin
  delete from mytable
  where createdate = (select min(createdate) from mytable)
  and (select count(*) from mytable) = 1000;
end;
```

I wouldn't recommend it, though, as I'd always fear mutating table errors.

Then you could use a record ID ranging from 1 to the desired maximum row count in combination with a cycling sequence. Rather then using INSERT you would then use MERGE based on this column and thus overwrite old records when the record ID gets re-used. With possible gaps in a sequence, you might not always overwrite the oldest record though.

So yes, there are possibilities (as they were before), but the easiest and cleanest is still the cron job you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for accepting my other answer. However, overnight I got another idea: An **after statement trigger** shouldn't cause mutating table errors, as far as I see it, so you might want to try this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_crop_mytable
after insert on mytable
begin
  delete from mytable
  where rowid in
  (
    select mytable_rowid
    from
    (  
      select 
        mytable.rowid as mytable_rowid,
        row_number() over (order by createdate desc) as cnt
      from mytable
    )
    where cnt > 1000
  );  
end;
```

This fires once after an insert statement; no matter if it inserted one or 20,000 rows. It gives each row a rowcount number starting with #1 for the newest. Then it deletes as many old rows as needed to get back to 1000 rows in the table.

The only issue with this I see so far is performance: Every insert statement will lead to sorting and numbering all the rows in order to dispose of the overage; this may take some time with a large table.

Comment: I like this solution since it keeps everything in the database and it's quite straight-forward, but upon applying it my Spring application just throws the following exception, without much other explanation: `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction`

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work. And worse that Java/Spring hides the actual error from us. Maybe a DBA can look at the database while this happens and explain the error. But well, maybe it *is* a simple timeout due to table size and long execution time.